# My image as a brush alpha is stretched, how do I fix this?

Tags: modeling, transparency, image, sculpting

I'm trying to use an image as a brush alpha, and stencil later, but when I upload it the texture always appears stretched compared to my original image.

I've included how it should be with a screenshot to show what I mean, I understand it's not black and white, blurred etc as it's an example.

[image: Original image]

[image: Uploaded texture]

How do I fix the image so in the preview and when applied the shape doesn't change?

Answer (score 0):

Make your original image square (1x1) or in the *N panel > Tool >Brush Settings > Texture* (or on the top menu as in image below), click on the *Image Aspect* button:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked, I tried to fix the image aspect under a different heading I think but I must have not checked properly, anyway this is much appreciated!!